# Best way to have nested enums in Kotlin?

Tags: swift, kotlin, enums, nested, operators

So in Swift you can do something like:

```
public enum OuterEnum {
    public enum InnerEnum {
       ...
    }
}
```

What would the equivalent be in Kotlin to contain an enum inside an enum?

Comment: Being organized and not having to create a new package?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can create an inner enum as follows:

```
enum class OuterEnum {
    OUTER_ITEM1;
    enum class InnerEnum {
        INNER_ITEM1, INNER_ITEM2
    }
}
```

Or if you don't have items in the `OuterEnum`:

```
enum class OuterEnum {
    ;
    enum class InnerEnum {
        INNER_ITEM1, INNER_ITEM2
    }
}
```

Note that there is a **semicolon** before declaration of the `InnerEnum`.
To use it just call:

```
val item = OuterEnum.InnerEnum.INNER_ITEM1
```

Comment: Is there a way to also have it work as function parameter? for example if I have a `fun someWork(type: OuterEnum)` then it wont take `InnerEnum` as an argument

Comment: I believe you must have `type: OuterEnum.InnerEnum` as the parameter to make it work.